# Pulling out Conditional Expectation from a Rational Function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X,Y$ be two (possibly dependent) random variables with $X,Y>-1$. I would like to evaluate the expected value of a ratio
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1+Y}{1+X}\right]$$ and stuck on some steps; see detail below.

> My thought: Using conditonal expectation. For $y>-1$,
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1+Y}{1+X}\right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1+Y}{1+X} | \ Y=y\right]\right]\\
> &= \mathbb{E}\left[ (1+y) \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{1+X} | \ Y=y\right]\right]\\
> &\geq \mathbb{E}\left[ (1+y) \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[1+X| \ Y=y]} \right] \;\;\; \rm{By \ Jensen's \ inequality.}
> \end{align*}
> $$
> However, I am not sure if the conditional expection (I know if standard expectation, I can, but not sure for conditional one.) can be pulled out? That is, I wonder
> $$
> \mathbb{E}\left[ (1+y) \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[1+X| \ Y=y]} \right] = ? = \underbrace{\mathbb{E}\left[ 1+y \right]\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[1+X| \ Y=y]}}_{=(1+y)\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[1+X| \ Y=y]}}. 
> $$

Any thought/comment is appreciated.

Comment: Jensen's inequality holds for conditional expectations too - [link](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4410/h19/undervisningsmateriale/jensen.pdf)

Comment: @P.J. Thanks for the reply. My question is not about Jensen. It is about whether I can  factor out the conditional expectation; see my last equality with question mark "=?=".

Comment: you have that $$\operatorname{E}\left[\frac{1+Y}{1+X}\right]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1+y}{1+x}\mathop{}\!d F_{X,Y}(x,y)$$ where $F_{X,Y}$ is the joint distribution and $dF_{X,Y}$ the associated Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure. Without more information this cannot be simplified further

Comment: @Masacroso, Thanks for the reply. Yes. I agree that without more information, the reatio cannot be simplified further. However, regarding my question about pulling out the conditional expectation, is that step legitmate? i.e, $$
\mathbb{E}\left[ (1+y) \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[1+X| \ Y=y]} \right] = ? = \underbrace{\mathbb{E}\left[ 1+y \right]\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[1+X| \ Y=y]}}_{=(1+y)\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[1+X| \ Y=y]}}. 
$$

Comment: @Fianra it cannot be legitimate as the expression $E[1+y]$ is not well-defined

Comment: @Fianra as others have pointed out, you cannot take the conditional expectation out of the expectation. Think of it this way. The conditional expectation in the most general case would be a function of $y$. Since the external expectation is wrt to Y one cannot pull out a function of $y$ from the integral assuming it to be a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear to me the symbol $y$ that you introduce. If the question is if this holds as an equality :

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ (1+Y) \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[1+X| \ Y]} \right] = ? = \mathbb{E}\left[ 1+Y \right]\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[1+X| \ Y]}
$$

Than I would argue that it does not make much sense since on the right we have a Y measurable random variable, and on the left a (deterministic) scalar.

This instead would work if $\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[1+X| \ Y]}$ and $1+Y$ were independent:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ (1+Y) \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[1+X| \ Y]} \right] = ? = \mathbb{E}\left[ 1+Y \right]\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[1+X| \ Y]}\right]
$$

but not in a general case.